# Is there any free Visual Studio plug-in/extension or external program to visualize XAML DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml, datatemplate

Visual Studio (10) gives the expected message "Intentionally Left Blank" in the designer.
I know already that I can do this with Blend, just looking around if there is an alternative solution... 
I don’t really mind to graphically edit the template; I want only to see it without having to run the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you might want, but you can use [XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and just paste the content of your datatemplate into it. As long as you don't have layout related bindings, it should work well. Bindings are just ignored by xamlpad, and you need to add the 2 wpf namespace aliases by hand.

for example:

```
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Text="{Binding test}" 
   Background="Red"
   Width="20" Height="20"/>
```

the textblock is empty in XamlPad, but everything else works as expected.